# Primefaces <p:graphicimage> giving 404 while using apache httpd mod-rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, primefaces, apache

I created a simple application with a single jsp file and used primefaces, Here is the code

**index.jsp:**

```
 <%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" prefix="p" %>
 <p:graphicImage value="/image/Kitty.gif"/>
```

httpd.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost localhost:80>
   ProxyPass /sayHello http://localhost:8080/sayHello
   ProxyPassReverse /sayHello http://localhost:8080/sayHello
 </VirtualHost>
```

If i run the application directly (http://localhost:8080/sayHello) the image is displaying
but if i run it by using apache (http://localhost/sayHello) it fails. I also tried manually hitting the generated URL and i believe Apache is not redirecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the proxy pass to the root URI:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Or also proxy the image directory:

```
ProxyPass /sayHello http://localhost:8080/sayHello
ProxyPassReverse /sayHello http://localhost:8080/sayHello

ProxyPass /image http://localhost:8080/image
ProxyPassReverse /image http://localhost:8080/image
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it works(both)!! now if i make the image click-able 
       <p:commandLink type="submit" id="goButton" action="null" ajax="false">
         <p:graphicImage value="/image/Kitty.gif"/>
     </p:commandLink>
I'm keeping the action to null so that it just refreshes.
if i hit the http://localhost/sayHello and then click on the image. The page loads as http://localhost:8080/sayHello. Moreover i saw the generated URL for the image in firebug its  http://localhost:8080/<gibberish>. I want the image to load as http://localhost/<gibberish>

Comment: @anandramani try including the `ProxyPassReverse` for the `/image` directory (edited my answer)